# Deleting the scheduled notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am scheduling events and creating the notification for the same on weekly basis or daily basis.The notification is being displayed at correct time.

**Problem**
I want to delete the notification once the scheduled event is deleted. But I get the notification even if event is deleted. I tried deleting the **Pending Intent** by passing the same unique_id(**eventId**) that I have used for creating that intent, but its not deleting. Please find my code below:

**creating notification**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        HABIT_NAME  = habitName.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("HABIT_NAME", habitName.getText().toString());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), eventId, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(daysNo.size() == 7){           //alarm for every day
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,reminderLifeTS.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent); 
        }else{                            // specific days of week
            for(int i=0;i<daysNo.size();i++){
                int day = getWeek(daysNo.get(i));
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, reminderLifeTS.get(Calendar.MINUTE));    
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        c.getTimeInMillis(),7*24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
            }
        }
```

**Service class**

```
mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().
                   getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

           intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

           PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                   this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

           // megha
           NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                   .setContentTitle("DharmaLife")
                   .setContentText(AddScheduleEventActivity.HABIT_NAME)
                   .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

           Notification note = mBuilder.build();
           note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
           note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
           note.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

           PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
           WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
                   PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
           wakeLock.acquire();
```

**Deleting Notification**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), eventId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

**EDIT**
to keep the list of all the pending intents created, I am saving it in arrayList along with its unique id:

```
notificationData.setAlarmManager(alarmManager);
notificationData.setPendingIntent(pendingIntent);
notificationData.setEventId(eventId);
LifeLiteral.NOTIFICATION_STACK.add(notificationData);
```

to delete the notification:

```
for(NotificationData i : LifeLiteral.NOTIFICATION_STACK){
    if(i.getEventId() == eventId){
    pendingIntent = i.getPendingIntent();
    alarmManager = i.getAlarmManager();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

but still notifications are not getting deleted. Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

When attempting to delete the `PendingIntent` you aren't passing an `Intent` that matches the original `Intent` (because the `Intent` you pass to `getBroadcast()` is empty). Change your delete code to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),
    eventId, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
// Cancel the `PendingIntent` after you've canceled the alarm
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

Comment: I am still getting notification.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are using the same `eventId` to delete them?

Comment: I'm confused. What triggers the notification? Does this happen when the alarm goes off?

Comment: same here, I am storing notifications in an array, and deleting them in the same way, and it does not get dismissed from the list of notifications..

Comment: @Async- please post a new question with your problem and your code and we can help you. Making a comment here isn't helpful to you or anyone else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595594/notification-is-not-being-dismissed-android/37610495
please can you help me with this?

Comment: U save me! tks!